# Indexing items in a text file line, building a list to append a list

Tags: list, file, text, build

I am new to Python, so bear with my wrongthink...I am sure there are better ways to do what I am doing, but for what I have here, I have a question about picking out items in a text file to build a list.

I have a program that has a nested list setup. Each nested list is employee information. The user input builds the list how I need it, like [['name1',ssn1,'phone1','email1','salary1'],['name2',ssn2,'phone2','email2','salary2']] and so forth. I can save the information, and the text file looks like this:

John Doe,123456789,(443)555-1212,john@doe,$12345

Jane Doe,123456788,(443)555-1234,jane@doe,$12345

(For above, There isnt a blank line between the lines in my actual text file, the editor here crammed them together, so I did put a new line between them)
I want to open the text file and bring the list back in the same fashion as the user input list described above.

So now my question: How does one address one item from one list? In other words, to pick out the items between the commas... right now I am building my list like this:

def load_file():

```
with open('employee_file.txt') as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    size = len(text)
print(size)
#cont()
for line in open('employee_file.txt'):
    items = line.rstrip('\n').split('\t')   
    items = [item.strip() for item in items]  
    for i in range(0,size-1):       

        loading_build=[items[i][0],
                items[i][1],
                items[i][2],
                items[i][3],
                items[i][4]]
        list_emp_info.append(loading_build)
print(list_emp_info)
cont()
```

my loading_build is assembling a list then that list is appended to my list_emp_info list.

The list that this code builds looks like this:

[['J', 'o', 'h', 'n', ' '], ['J', 'a', 'n', 'e', ' ']]
Press Enter to Continue...

I get what its doing...giving me the first five characters of each line, but what I want is the first five (well all five) items between the commas. The structure of the list is how I want it at least.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I feel it is something simple I am missing.

Comment: Well, I've realized my mistake here, I only needed this: loading_build=[items[i]], That way it brings in whole lines or "i" in this case, not some sub index of "i".

Comment: Ack!!!! Still, I need some way of specifying a single....whats the proper term? "item?" from the text file.... the thing is,  I need to take some of the words in my text file lines and specify that they are strings, or as I thought, just put " ' " on either side of them. So that is what I am after now..... something like "put a ' on either side of current line, item 1,3,4,5".  I guess I could append them AFTER they are loaded in my resident list...hmmmm. Im really sorry for rambling, I have ADD (really), I overthink things too much and I know it is frustrating to make sense out of me